# Generic type in Promise

Tags: scala, generics, promise, future

I designed a class Task to compute some value T synchronously.
Now I want provide a way to retrieve the value asynchronously.

This is the first time I use Promise in Scala. I wrote the following code:

```scala
abstract class Task[+T](
...

    final def result: Try[T] = {
        if (state != TaskState.Terminated)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Task must be terminated")
        cached_result
    }
}



// OTHER CLASS
    private val executedTasks = HashMap[TaskID, Task[_]]() 
    private val promises = HashMap[TaskID, Promise[Any]]()

    ...

    def onTaskEvent(taskEvent: TaskEvent): Unit = {
        ...
        val task: Task[_] = ...
        promises.get( task.id ).foreach( p => p complete task.result ) // fulfill the promise with a Try[_]
        ...
    }

    ...

    /**
    * if the task exists and is terminated I return the result immediately
    * otherwise I make a promise
    */
    def getTaskResult(uuid: TaskID): Future[_] = {
        executedTasks.get(uuid) match {
            case Some(task) if task.state == TaskState.Terminated => Future.fromTry(task.result)
            case _ => {
                val p = Promise[Any]()
                promises.put(uuid, p)
                p.future
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works but I want to get rid of that ugly `Any` in Promise and continue to use generic types. When I tried to use `Promise[_]` I get mysterious compiler error of the kind `"expected: Try[_] actual: Try[_$1]"` or `"Promise[_]: unbound wildcard type"`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no relationship between the type parameters of `Task` and `Promise` for the same key if you use `Promise[_]`; you could have e.g. a `Task[Int]` and a `Promise[String]`, in which case `p complete task.result` makes no sense. But honestly, I'd argue that in this case what you have is pretty much the best you can do (without changing the design significantly) for two reasons:

1. `Future` is covariant, so `Future[_]` is basically equivalent to `Future[Any]`.
2. > if the task exists and is terminated I return the result immediately otherwise I make a promise

   If the task doesn't exist, do you have a way to know what its type parameter is going to be?

Comment: See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a satisfying design for my need, while enforcing typing.
Basically, the idea is that the caller of *getTaskResult* knows which type he expects for a given task. So it's not abnormal to cast the elements of the generic collection to the expected type when you retrieve them. I solved also the problem of multiple promises for the same task with a multimap.

```
    protected val promises = new HashMap[TaskID, collection.mutable.Set[Promise[_]]] with collection.mutable.MultiMap[TaskID, Promise[_]]

    ...

    protected def makePromise[T](task: Task[T]): Promise[T] = {
        val p = Promise[T]()
        promises.addBinding(task.id, p)
        p
    }

    protected def fulfillPromise[T](task: Task[T]): Unit =
        promises.remove(task.id).foreach(p => p.map(_.asInstanceOf[Promise[T]]).foreach(_ complete task.result))


    protected def futureResult[T](task: Task[T]): Future[T] = {
        if (task.state == TaskState.Terminated)
            Future.fromTry(task.result)
        else
            makePromise(task).future
    }


    def getTaskResult[T](uuid: TaskID): Future[T] =
        taskTracker.getTaskById(uuid).map(_.asInstanceOf[Task[T]]).fold(throw new Exception("Unknown task"))(futureResult(_))
```

Comment: You could have the expected type on the TaskID as well:
def getTaskResult[T](uuid: TaskID[T]): Future[T] =
        taskTracker.getTaskById(uuid).mapTo[Task[T]].fold(throw new Exception("Unknown task"))(futureResult(_))

Comment: TaskID is currently mapped to the UUID type

Comment: type TaskId[T] = UUID

Answer (score 0):

hum, I feel there is still a problem with this function:

```
protected def fulfillPromise[T](task: Task[T]): Unit =
        promises.remove(task.id).foreach(p => p.map(_.asInstanceOf[Promise[T]]).foreach(_ complete task.result))
```

It is not protected against ClassCastException in the scope of the notifier, I think there is a need to use TypeTag in Promise here.